# Serverless-webpack deploy script is "hanging" with Webpack 4.8, while running ok with 3.12.

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm using serverless and serverless-webpack. `webpack` config is pretty straightforward:

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        lambda: './lambda.js',
    },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: __dirname,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        }, {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json-loader',
        }],
    },
    stats: "verbose",
};
```

serverless.yml:

```
plugins:
    - serverless-webpack
    - serverless-secrets-plugin
    - serverless-plugin-split-stacks
    - serverless-offline  

custom:
    webpack:
        webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs8.10

functions:
    lambdaFn:
        handler: lambda.fn
        events:
            - http: GET /foo
```

When deploying with webpack version 8.4 the console output is absolutely clear (even with `verbose` on), and the node process consumes 0% CPU:

```
node ./node_modules/.bin/serverless offline -p 3001 -s local
Serverless: Bundling with Webpack...
```

When downgrading webpack to 3.12 (latest 3.* version), the build runs successfully.

At least, how can I debug this? I'm not seeing any errors or hints in the output, unfortunately.

Comment: maybe missing a compiler flag? this happens with non TS files as well. Even future versions of webpack are not compatible with serverless-webpack plugin. webpack@4.4.15. I had to downgrade, and it works.

Comment: I think serverless-webpack is unmaintained now. I’ll work around it.

Comment: @FlavorScape what did you downgrade?